# Parse json from database

Tags: python, json

I want to extract from the database json, so I do:

Content json from database

'{ "rules": 98 }

```
def do():
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT content_json FROM page_s WHERE URL = 'page'")
    select = json.dumps(c.fetchone()) # return '{ "rules": 98 }
    extract = json.loads(select)
    print extract['rules']
```

But has an error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You do not mention:  What DB use are using, which line the error is on, what data type the column in question is, etc...

Comment: Why are you wasting cycles dumping `c.fetchone()` to JSON and then loading it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c.fetchone()` returns a tuple, in your case a 1-item tuple.

So I'd write:

```
print(extract[0]['rules'])
```

or directly at the source:

```
select = json.dumps(c.fetchone()[0])
```